# How does System.Guid.NewGuid() generate unique values?

Tags: asp.net

How does `System.Guid.NewGuid()` know that the values it generates are unique, for example when i use in a loop?
Does it internally store data somewhere? .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it uses pseudo-random numbers. See the [description of the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier#Algorithm) at Wikipedia.